# Emojis from api are not displayed properly

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this string from api

> \ud83d\ude18\ud83d\udc4c\ud83e\udd70\ud83d\ude02\ud83e\udd73\u2708\ufe0f\ud83d\udc4a\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude01\ud83e\udd23\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude01\u2708\ufe0f\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude4f\ud83e\udd22\ud83d\ude2d

and its not displaying the emoticons in a `Text widget`, however if I copy and paste it directly to a `Text widget`, the emoticons are showing up. What am I missing guys? Im totally lost right now.

I already tried some `utf8` decoding and still no luck, I also tried adding

```
"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

to my headers.

Comment: can you add your post JSON response and code how you fetching it  ?

Comment: here is my code for fetching data 
`
Future<List<Feed>> getFeeds(token) async {
    List<Feed> feeds = [];
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('$_root/feed'),
      headers: {
        "authorization": "Bearer $token",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      },
    );
    final parsedJson = json.decode(response.body);
    print(parsedJson);
    final data = parsedJson["data"];
    
    final feed = (data as List).map((i) => Feed.fromJson(i)).toList();
    feeds.addAll(feed);
    return feeds;
  }`

Comment: if you have `String emoticons;` what do you see if you `print(emoticons.runes.first);`?

Comment: Im not using runes upon displaying the emoticons @pskink

Comment: ok what do you see if you `print(emoticons.codeUnitAt(0))`; then? is it really `55357`?

Comment: codeUnit returns 84 @pskink

Comment: so your first character in your `String` is capital letter `T` (check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) - i dont see it in the string you posted

Comment: @pskink yes, here is my full string Testing emoticons post \ud83d\ude18\ud83d\udc4c\ud83e\udd70\ud83d\ude02\ud83e\udd73\u2708\ufe0f\ud83d\udc4a\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude01\ud83e\udd23\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude01\u2708\ufe0f\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude4f\ud83e\udd22\ud83d\ude2d

Comment: because I thought it will consider as a same string with the emoticons. Is it possible to decode that kind of string? @pskink

Comment: @pskink I cannot remove it, since its coming from the api.